# Why center printing doesn't work upon custom struct?

Tags: rust

First I write a struct:

```rust
struct sdt {
    name: String,
    sex: bool
}
```

Then **impl** *`Display`* for it:

```rust
impl Display for sdt {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "<{}, {}>", self.name, self.sex)
    }
}
```

Now I want to print it centered as below:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{:^30}", "hello world!");
    let s = sdt {
        name: String::from("cheng-min"),
        sex: false
    };
    println!("{:^30}", s)
}
```

But It's output is:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An5Ve.png)

Could you please tell me what happened and how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format specifiers don't do any work on their own. They get passed to the `Formatter` object you call `f` in your `Display` implementation, and your function can do with them what it pleases.

For instance, to pad the resulting output to the given width (like many built-in types do), use [`Formatter::pad`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.pad)

```
impl Display for sdt {
  fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
    f.pad(&format!("<{}, {}>", self.name, self.sex))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it awesomely works! But one more question omitted, could I capture format specifiers and resolve them byte by byte?